# What is the reason behind the mosfet setup in circuits similar to the one shown in the image?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver

I searched and since I don't know what to search for I figured I'd rather just ask. I did find various things but nothing explaining why it's setup like that (as shown in the image below). The upper and lower mosfet's.  I would like to understand why it's setup like that and what exactly is happening there. (if possible)

I have seen this type of setup at a few places like even on the laptop charging circuit for the battery. The phase pin would usually run in between two mosfet's similar to the way "TRIGGER" is on the right in the image below.

Thanks

[image: Random Image from the web]

## Edit: Added schematic image of a similar circuit, which contains more detail...

- Seems like it's not a well known thing... according to the comments...

[image: 3v_5v_alwp]

Comment: please show a schematic ... the block diagram is unclear ... there is probably some text that goes with the block diagram

Comment: Schematics? We haven't got any schematics. We don't _need_ any stinking schematics!

Comment: 'every component must be available to make it work' - yeah, because normally you can miss a few components without major issues...

Comment: I added a schematic image, hope it helps...

Comment: This arrangement is called a half-bridge. It is frequently used in buck converters (like the schematic) and other power conversion circuitry. Now that you know what it is called, maybe you can find more applicable search results that will explain what it does.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you so much! I'm sure I'll be able to find info on it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of that schematic is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDOhBA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's the schematic of a step-down (buck) converter. Your schematic has two, one for 3.3V, and one for 5V.

The *drive* MOSFET is turned on for a short time and runs a current from +BAT through the coil into the +3.3V output. Then, it's turned off and the body diode of the *commutation* MOSFET takes over the current through the coil 
*L*, which cannot be turned off in an instant (it's a coil!). The *commutation* MOSFET is turned on to limit the losses introduced by its own body diode. Then, the commutation MOSFET is turned off again and the cycle begins another time. The control checks the voltage on the output and turns on/off the mosfets so it's regulated to 3.3V.

Comment: Could you please label the inductor? I think this might not help a beginner very much if they don't know what the black rectangle is supposed to be.

Comment: Oh. It's the IEC symbol of an inductor.

Comment: @Janka Thanks I get what's happening in the circuit. But I just didn't know the reason for the placement of the mosfets... now that mkeith told me what it is i can further research. Thanks tho. #edit: Oh you added more detail. Thanks for adding some explanation it makes more sense now.

Comment: A solid black rectangle is the IEC symbol for an inductor? Well, I didn't know. Haha!

Comment: You will stumble across them as soon you read schematics made by Europeans.